# Creating external switch breaks internet connection

Tags: networking, hyper-v

I'm trying to set up my Hyper-V settings propertly so that I have internet connection on my host as well as on my VM.

I've googled a lot and found many useful links, especially [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021277/how-to-connect-visual-studio-2015-android-emulator-to-network/43615819#43615819), but it didn't solve my problem.

As soon as I create an external switch with default settings (as seen in the image below), my host loses connection to the internet.

[image]

When I look at my network connections, I can see that the external switch is stuck at "identifying network...". Maybe this indicates what might be the problem, but I'm not experienced enough in networks to figure this out.

[image]

I uninstalled Xamarin Android Emulator and I never had genymotion installed. I also can't see any old network adapters which might be causing this problem:

[image]

At this point, I am basically lost. I didn't find any solution which helped me. Does anyone have an idea what I could try?